# Is there a way to check 'adminPassword' when attempting to login?

Tags: laravel

The problem is that my login won't go through if I use the `adminPassword` value in database.

Initially, after user logged in, they are going to be prompted to change their default password.

We are bombarded with questions about why my account has no access to this and that.

Since they changed their password, we are unable to check if, after updating its role, they have the access already.

So, my goal is to put an `adminPassword` where I can login their account and check if it's already okay - their access.

I've tried to override the `attemptlogin`. First `if` is to check if the credentials are correct with the `password` and `email`. (Normal login)

If no users found with the `password` value, then next is to check `adminPassword`. (Admin-like login) I can't seem to fix this.

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    if($this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return true;
    }

    $email = request('email');
    dump($email);
    $password = request('password');
    dump($password);

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'adminPassword' => $password]))
    {
        return true;
    }


    // $credentials = array(['email' => $this->credentials($request)['email'], 'adminPassword' => \Hash::make($this->credentials($request)['password'])]);

    // return $this->guard()->attempt(
    //     reset($credentials), $request->has('remember')
    // );
}
```

Actual results is to be able to login still when using adminPassword.

Comment: what is your problem, please say shorter:) do you have adminPassword column in your table?

Comment: Yes, there is. I put a adminPassword value on all users. And I wanna login a user's account via credentials' email and adminPassword. This does not mean that I wanna remove the default login. It will still be there. Since I don't know their password, I need to use adminPassword.

Comment: Usually, users report their problem to us devs/supports. Their problem is working on my local app, but not on production. I need to login their account to check/debug the error.

Comment: did you save hashed numbers in adminPassword column value?I think you saved plain numbers and laravel attempt cant read value of its value

Comment: Instead of using hash:make have you tried Hash:check()? See if its return true.

Comment: @atf.sgf I hashed the value, and saved the value for all users in database.

Comment: @LimKeanPhang I did actually Hash::check() it and it returns true. Now, I tried the following [coode](https://pastebin.com/raw/2HJZ5BC0) but I think the password in attempt is still hashing the value so it does not equal with the stored value in database,

Comment: Hash::check will auto hash the second parameter so you need to hash your $password manually after the Hash::check

You need to add a $password = Hash::make($password = $user->password;)

Comment: @LimKeanPhang Please see my code below. I used the Hash::check() and, if returns true, I login the user by Auth::login().

Comment: That's an alternative way to login as well perhaps you can try remove the Hash::check and see if it works too?

Comment: If I remove Hash::check(), it will then proceed since I only check email unless email not found in db. Adding another ->where('adminPassword', request('password')) or ->where('adminPassword', \Hash::make(request('password'))) would not go through since first one is not equal to hashed password and second one is hashing the password value and it will not be the same with saved hashed password in database. So, I think Hash::check() is the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually logging the user after using `Hash::check()` method on both password value and hashed password on database.

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    if($this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')))
        return true;

    $user = User::where('email', request('email'))->first();
    if($user) {
        if(\Hash::check(request('password'), $user->adminPassword)) {
            Auth::login($user);
            session()->put('justAdmin', true);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```